# Code from the comments sometimes comes with non-printable characters

Tags: support, bug

Okay, so this is a really weird issue, and I'm not sure how to explain it.

Steps to reproduce (doesn't happen all the time):

1. Write a line of code in a comment, it should be inside `backticks`.
2. Try and copy that line of code
3. You'll see the code may now have non-printable characters introduced.

I've an example for you ready. [Here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47184452/reindexing-on-a-datetime-to-interpolate-new-values#comment81318465_47184452). I wrote the following in a comment:

```
df.set_index('Year').resample('A').interpolate(method='linear')
```

OP complained of syntax errors running this code, so I copied it, and found it had this:

```
df.set_index('Year').resample('A').interpolate(method='linea\u200c\u200br')
```

Note the characters at the end.

What is this?

Edit: Using *Safari Version 11.0.1 (12604.3.5.1.1)*

I was also able to repro this on *Chrome Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)*

Comment: Well, I'm using Chrome ( 61.0.3163.100 64-bit ). I can't reproduce. Have you tried other browsers besides Safari? (Not to switch to for personal use, to repro the bug :) )

Comment: @StoryTeller Since you asked, I tried it on chrome and the result's the same...

Comment: Oh well. Here's hoping someone comes along with the same bug

Comment: @Will Ah, so it is a known issue. If you could paraphrase the answer (I'm not a JS person) in such a way that I could understand, that would be great...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this answer on meta.se](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/171065/1228):

Unicode magic is inserted in comments (not just in `` `code` ``) whenever no whitespace was seen for about 80 characters, to enforce line wrapping. Without that the layout can really be messed up.

Jeff once [explained why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5460/post-overflow/42662#42662) this magic is needed:

> The `word-wrap:break-word` suggestion is a good one.
>
> Works fine on posts, which are fixed width, and that is implemented.
>
> Near as I can tell, there is *no* way to get this to work on comments because they are variable width. That is, the actual comment size depends on whether or not the comment vote UI controls are present (fex, on your own comment, you don't have controls, if you're not logged in there are no controls, etc), and if the comment has say 100 upvotes that's wider still.

Comment: This made supporting languages with no spaces (e.g. Japanese) quite interesting :)